# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input error using Gulp and main-bower-files package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, gulp, bower

I keep getting an error trying to inject the main bower files into my build folder index.html

I am using the [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) NPM [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/main-bower-files).

My code looks like this:

```
//requires
var gulp = require('gulp');
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var config = require('./gulp-config');
var mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('default', ['move'], function() {
  return gulp
    .src(config.buildFolder + config.indexFile)
    .pipe(
  inject(
    gulp.src( mainBowerFiles()  ), {base: './bower_components'}
    )
  )
.pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildFolder));
});

gulp.task('move', function() {
  return gulp
    .src(config.indexFile)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.buildFolder));
});
```

which gives me the following error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So this one really bugged me (I was peeking under the hood at the NPM package code to see if there really was an unexpected end of input error, but the error was my fault).

The problem is in my file structure, I had an empty .bowerrc file that I generated from the terminal by typing `$ touch .bowerrc`. Just add

```
{
    "directory": "(your bower components folder here as valid JSON)"
}
```

and... the error is gone! hope this saves someone else as much trouble as it caused me.

Comment: Yup, this little thing just tried to ruin my day. Thank you sir! Anyway, if you have the `bower_components` folder set up as usual, and you don't need any further configuration, you can just delete the `.bowerrc` file.

Comment: Another thing that might cause this error is an interrupted install, which can be fixed by removing the component directory, (`bower_components` by default) and rerunning the install.